# Raphaeljs fill the circle with an image

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Okay then we have a basic situation, that is drawing a circle and filling it with an image. 
This can be easily done by using:

el.attr({'fill': 'url(image_url)'});

but the above has a disadvantage of not scaling the image to fit in the circle.

So essentially I'm looking for something like this (CSS based):

http://jsfiddle.net/hKyzT/

any hints?

Any help appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a modified version of Raphaël that does that:

http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/raphaeljs/fill-shape-with-image.html