# Fill a Raphael circle with an image + border

Tags: javascript, raphael

I've created a red circle with Raphael, I want to fill it with an image that will fit the whole circle (if not rounded first).

This is my canvas with the red circle and the image I want to fit in :

[image]

**READING OPTIONAL** : Why without CSS ? Already did it, but was not responsive. In fact, when I was resizing my window, the image did not follow the circle.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please share current status as fiddle, you have no code in your question

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Raphael. You could look into Snap.svg, Raphaels modern sister and clip paths. Or you could take a look at this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274137/raphaeljs-fill-the-circle-with-an-image